# Need help in replacing contents of microsoft 2007 (HWPFDocument) document using apache poi

Tags: apache, apache-poi, java

First of all i m feeling its not very easy to use Apache POI API, as like any other java API's because i am confused which are all jar files needed in case of modifying contents of docx for this i am using poi-scratchpad-3.1-beta1.jar and poi-3.2-FINAL-20081019.jar (HWPFDocument class) but in some forums it was pointing to some other poi jar file different name along with different versions... (indicating to use the class XSSFDocument).

My requirement is to replace some text with some file contents.
for this i am using the following code to replace the contents of microsoft 2007 (docx file). and i have ended up with the error saying..

**org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.OfficeXmlFileException: The supplied data appears to be in the Office 2007+ XML. POI only supports OLE2 Office documents**

```
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.poi.POIDocument;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.usermodel.CharacterRun;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.usermodel.Range;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem;

public class GenerateTicket {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final String FILE_PATH = "/home/mateen/Desktop/Ticket.docx";
        try {
            File file = new File(FILE_PATH);
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            POIFSFileSystem poifs = new POIFSFileSystem(fis);
            HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(poifs);
            Range range = doc.getRange();
            CharacterRun run = range.insertAfter("Hello POI CORE/HWPF !!!");
            run.setBold(true);
            run.setItalic(true);
            doc.write(new FileOutputStream("/home/mateen/Desktop/FromTicket.Docx"));

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

so...

- is there any body who knows why two separate jar files are needed
- what i can do to make my code work ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HWPF works on the older, OLE2 based .doc files. If you want to work with the newer OOXML .docx files, you need to use XWPF instead.

Next, you're using older versions of POI, and mismatched ones at that. You should make sure you're using the latest version, and make sure all your POI jars are all from the same version. To work out what Jars you want, and what dependencies they have, see the [component overview page](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html) for details.

Comment: @sam: Please do not reply to a post by *editing the post*. And when you have a new question in particular, please feel free to, well, [*ask*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask "Ask Question") a new question.